# Google search links: command for subdomains?

Tags: google-search, subdomain, backlinks

The Google search's `links:` command allows one to retrieve a set of known backlinks to a domain.

Unfortunately, when using this command with a subdomain (for example against `myblog.blogspot.com`) the set of returned links do not always point to the subdomain.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Google **link operator** was `link:`, not `links:`, so that may have been the problem.

Regardless, the `link:` operator became depreciated in early 2017, so you shouldn't use it.

Google does allow you to view a sample of links to your site here:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/external-links